# Is it possible to force a package to be called last in the entirety of the LaTeX, when called in the class file?

Tags: xetex, packages

I have designed a class that needs the [xepersian](/questions/tagged/xepersian) package. This package is unique in the way that it needs to be called last so it doesn't get overwritten. I usually define my packages in the class file using the "\RequirePackage".
Is there a way to force a package to be called last where it is called in the .cls file with the possibility of other packages being called using the \usepackage in the .tex file?

Comment: You can use `\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{xepersian}}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I see. Thanks.

Comment: @campa `\AfterEndPreamble` is too late to load a package. You'll get a `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`. The `\AtBeginDocument` is the latest a package can be loaded because right after that the preamble ends (_i.e._ preamble-only commands become error messages).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik assuming that none of the packages you load later use the same trick to delay some package loading ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, yes, there's that. If I recall correctly, there's an infamous Brazilian class file which does something like that and loading `hyperref` on top of it is a nightmare :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can delay the package loading using `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{xepersian}}
```

this will put the package loading after the `.aux` file is read but before the “proper end” of the preamble, where all the preamble-only commands are redefined to throw an error; from this point on any `\usepackage` (or `\RequirePackage`) will not work.

If the package, for some reason, needs to be loaded before the `\begin{document}` even starts, then you can load the `etoolbox` package and use:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{document}{\RequirePackage{xepersian}}
```

this will execute the `\RequirePackage` before executing anything from the `\begin{document}`. The effect is the same as if you had put the `\RequirePackage` line right before `\begin{document}` in your `.tex` file.

Comment: What do you mean  by the "proper end" of the preamble? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Al_Fh I just invented that name :P I clarified the answer.

Comment: Of course, you can always load xpersian in the preamble (before hyperref).  It will not be loaded twice.